# Unity - Too many verts in a small 2D scene

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I had around 500 verts in my scene, then I found out that my mesh type was set to tight, I changed it to Full Rect and now I have 360 verts.

So my question is: is it ok to have 360 verts in a scene with 11 square sprites?
If not (I really feel like that's too many), how else can I lower the amount of verts?

EDIT: My problem was very stupid, that was UI that added most of those verts.

Comment: In Scene view you can change display mode from `Shaded` to `Shaded Wireframe` so you can see created triangles.

Comment: I cannot image that little amount causing any issues, mobile game might have hundreds of thousands vertices on screen.. Does your sprites get batched?

Comment: This amount didn't cause any issues, but that was just wierd that 11 square sprites needed that many verts. I found the cause now, and it was really stupid, most of the verts are the UI's ones.

Anyway, thanks for help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that 360 verts for one full scene is way more than OK. Unity is capable of rendering 65534 verts for only one mesh object, so less than 1k in a scene seems okay to me. It's always good to reduce verts amount to a minimum, but even if you can't, with 360, your game should run smoothly on almost everything.

Source for the vertex limit per object : [This Unity forum post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/255405/vertex-limit.html)

EDIT : If you still wish to lower the amount of verts, and don't mind spending a bit of money, you might wanna look at [SpriteSharp](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/37599). Or you can edit your sprites with any image editor to lower its size, it might work, but not certain. Again, the number of verts you actually have is fine, you probably shouldn't lower the graphical quality of your game for a few verts.